# Decrease the cost of one-to-one joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have some performance issues, and I think most of them are related to joins.
Most of queries run against views, and views are just enriched version of the table, like it gets the city name, user full name, etc.

For each query, system first takes a count of items in that view including applications wise filters and user provided filters,then brings a subset of those items, like first 20, then 2nd 20, etc.

The count queries are expensive.
Paging also gets worse when you head towards the last pages.

1. All of my tables have a uniqueidentifier field as the primary key.
2. We are using EntityFramework 5.0, and yes this queries are all
   generated by LINQ.
3. Most of my joins in the view definition are "Left Joins".
4. We are not using any kind of database foreign key, no constraints at
   all.

So what can we do (without touching number 1 & 2) to improve performance?

**EDIT:**
I have checked the view definition, there are 13 joins 2 of them to the same table (users), which has like 2.000 records, another table that has a join has like close to 1.000 records, and the rest have very few lets say 10-100 records at most. So creating an index on 13 uniqueidenitifer fields seem costly to me.

I think the problem is that SQL is checking the return row count of the left joins, and that is causing performance issue. Any ideas on how can I improve the performance on that part?

**EDIT2**
Lookup tables had translation tables, so adding unique index on the translation table for (ForeignKey + language code) improved the query performance tremendously.

Comment: Are the fields being used to join included in an index?

Comment: No. The fields that are used in the join are not included in an index.

Answer (score 2):

You should add indexes to the fields that are being used to join tables together, and those that are being used in the`WHERE` clause.  There are many resources available for advice on building effective indexes.  They will drastically increase performance.

[SQL Server Index Design Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095.aspx)

Example syntax on a table of transactions:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_acct_dt ON tbl_Transactions (Acct_No, Txn_Dt)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_amt ON tbl_Transactions (Txn_Amt)
```

I like my index names to indicate which fields are indexed when possible, but you can name them however you like.

When using views, indexes on the underlying tables are used, but you can also index the view itself.  Indexes to the underlying tables can help performance outside of the view, so it's preferable to build good indexes on the underlying tables, then evaluate index need on the view specifically.

Comment: I have checked the view, there are 13 joins 2 of them to the same table (users), which has like 2.000 records (actually has an index on that field), another table that has a join has like close to 1.000 records, and the rest have very few lets say 10-100 records at most. So creating an index on 13 uniqueidenitifer fields seem costly to me.

Comment: I cannot predict what the users will filter on, because we let them filter on anything, but yes I have indexes that I know that would be used a lot.

Comment: There is a cost to creating indexes in storage and insert/update performance, but they almost universally help with `SELECT` (there are pitfalls, over-indexing is a thing, but usually even then an index just doesn't get used by the optimizer rather than actually hurting performance).